# Generating an ICS file works on Desktop browser but not iOS browsers on ASP page

Tags: c#, ios, download, safari, icalendar

I have a form that will generate an ICS calendar file. I have some code that -used- to work on Apple iOS devices, but now doesn't. The code hasn't changed at all. It was working for a few years and stopped recently. (I have an iOS 15 device and an iOS 14 device and neither works).

It works fine on Desktop browsers (Windows - Edge, Chrome, Mac - Safari, Chrome). The strange behavior on iOS devices is: in Safari I get the error: 'Safari cannot download this file', in Chrome, the file downloads with the correct name (*.ICS) but the content of the file is the code of the current page (index.aspx  - the actual source file, not the runtime code).

My code is:

```
string myFileName = fileName.Text + ".ics"; // grabs the name from the page

//======= Download the ICS file.
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + myFileName + "\"");
Response.Charset = "utf-8";
Response.ContentType = "text/calendar";
Response.Output.Write(iCalContent.Text); //iCalContent contains the text for the calendar item
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

I've tried changing various options (Charset = "", Content-Disposition: inline, iCalContent.Text.ToString() ) but nothing works. I found some JS code that I could replace it with, but that doesn't give me the option for setting the file name.

This is code I have been using for 3 years, specifically because iOS has issues with ICS files hosted on our server and it was a solution that worked.

Comment: ever found a solution to this ?